# How to collect Application Crash Dumps

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, crash-dumps, windows-error-reporting

I need to collect the crash dumps for some specific applications. I have gone through this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181%28VS.85%29.aspx) but can't say it helped me much.

**Platform::** WinXP, Vista & Win7.

Seems that WinXP and above versions collect the dumps differently. For Example, say if I want to collect all dump files for IE, what would be the steps I should follow?

Comment: Quite unclear what you're asking for. Do you want to set up WER (Windows Error Reporting)? The title implies that you're having difficulty *collecting* crash dumps, which doesn't seem like it's very challenging task. So what are you asking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can the sysinternals (now Microsoft) tool called [procdump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx).

The tool is easy to use and straightforward for taking dump of a running process. You can take just in time dump too using procdump.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I do not need a tool. I need the coding guidelines.

Comment: Take a look at dbgHelp API. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679291%28v=vs.85%29.aspx You have to use function MiniDumpWriteDump.